# How can I start functions at very specific times in python?

Tags: python, time

I want to start a series of functions at very specific times. The resolution should be less then a millisecond.

I tried this setup with simpler functions.

```
from threading import Timer
import time

def func():
    tic = time.perf_counter()
    print(tic)
    return

t = Timer(5.0, func)
t2 = Timer(7.0, func)
t3 = Timer(9.0, func)
 
# Start the timer
t.start()
t2.start()
t3.start()
```

This is accurate in the `0.1` region and most of the time it is also accurate to the `0.01` region, but fails beyond this.
What I get out with the setup (for example) is the following:

```
4280.023567895
4282.029581234
4284.023852144
```

Is it possible to make the step in time to be beyond milliseconds exact? So that the output would look for example like this:

```
98765.4321whatever
98765.4321whatever
98765.4321whatever
```

Comment: General-purpose operating systems generally don't guarantee the ability to be scheduled with particular precision; you need to be on a RTOS or raw hardware to have firm guarantees about responsiveness to scheduled timer callbacks in _any_ language (and while things may have changed, back when I was in embedded systems, being able to have a garbage-collected language _and_ timing guarantees was a very rare combination; CPython's GC, in particular, is not known for being reliably low-latency, or at least, wasn't last time I had a handle on its performance characteristics).

Comment: In the first linked duplicate, note the addendum to the lone/accepted answer to the effect of "You'll need a busy-wait to get something _close_ to precision, and a proper RTOS to get the real thing").